# Why can't I call a class function inside the same class function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

It says this.draw is not defined but I have defined draw in the same class. Why can't I call a class function inside another class function?

```
function Recorder() {
  this.recording = false;
  this.sideLength = 5;
  this.currList = new SLinkedList(comparator);
  this.curr = null;
}

Recorder.prototype = {
  constructor:Recorder,

  draw : function (xPos, yPos) {

    if(recording) {
      currList.addEnd([xPos,yPos]);
    }

    let context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    let getColorPickerByID = document.getElementById("colors");
    let getValueOfColorPicker = getColorPickerByID.options[getColorPickerByID.selectedIndex].text;
    context.fillStyle = getValueOfColorPicker;
    context.fillRect(xPos,yPos,sideLength,sideLength); 
  },

  processMousePosition : function (evt){
    this.draw(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
  }

};
```

Comment: How is `processMousePosition` called?

Comment: Based on `evt` as argument you are probably passing `processMousePosition` as reference to an event listener which gives it a different calling context and `this` is an element. Show how it is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your class a method named `handleEvent`. Make this function check the `evt.type` and call the appropriate method for that event.

```
function Recorder() {
  this.recording = false;
  this.sideLength = 5;
  this.currList = new SLinkedList(comparator);
  this.curr = null;
}

Recorder.prototype = {
  constructor:Recorder,

  handleEvent : function(evt) {
    switch (evt.type) {
      case "mousemove":
        this.processMousePosition(evt);
        break;
    }
  },

  draw : function (xPos, yPos) {
     // your draw code
  },

  processMousePosition : function (evt){
    this.draw(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
  }
};
```

Then when you go to add the listener to the element, pass your instance of `Recorder` instead of its methods. This will cause the `handleEvent` method to be invoked when the event occurs.

```
var r = new Recorder();
myElement.addEventListener("mousemove", r);
```

Comment: @charlietfl: The value of `this` in the `handleEvent` method will be the instance of `Recorder`.

Comment: @charlietfl: Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sr5kn1cy/

Comment: My bad. Admit I leaned something new. Never new about the EventListener.handleEvent before. Just looked it up in docs...interesting

Comment: @charlietfl: Yep, it's really handy. Creates a nice connection between the DOM elements that have associated logic, and the logic itself. It's the one thing that can bring some actual structure and organization to a web application.

Comment: Right and don't even need to look up what method to pass to what listener